# Gradle error in resolving react-native-reanimated dependencies

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-emulator, react-native-reanimated

I am facing the error below in the picture when I am trying to build my react-native app on android emulator.

To give more detail it gets stuck in **configuring phase** when performing:

**(:react-native-reanimated > Resolve dependencies of :react-native-reanimated:classpath > gradle-7.3.0.pom)**

[image: **]

(By the way, ios simulator works perfectly fine!)

Version of the packages that I am using:

```
"react-native": "0.70.1",

"react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I spent a lot of time upgrading my react-native app and had some problems with react-native-reanimated has I remember.

Everything works perfectly now with "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0".

I don't know if it'll works for you but you can try to downgrade reanimated a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am going to post the answer myself, but this will only be useful for developers who work in locations in which google services like Android are sanctioned.

The problem was simply my internet connection being unable to download the **react-native-reanimated:classpath**.

So to solve this issue or any other similar issue in the configuration phase, you have to use a VPN to change the source of request to be able to download the required packages to get your build.